# How to download a huge gz file (around 3 GB size) from a URL where there is no file name present using python

Tags: python, url, python-requests, gzip

I am trying to download a file using python from a URL. However its not working and instead I am getting index.html.
Please help on same.

```
import requests

target_url = "https://transparency-in-coverage.uhc.com/?file=2022-07-01_United-HealthCare-Services_Third-Party-Administrator_EP1-50_C1_in-network-rates.json.gz&origin=uhc"

filename = "2022-07-01_United-HealthCare-Services_Third-Party-Administrator_EP1-50_C1_in-network-rates.json.gz"

with requests.get(target_url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: You're getting an html file because the URL points to a html website.

Comment: tkausl Ok then how can I get the actual gz file from that website ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're the URL you specified is for an HTML page that subsequently starts the download for the .gz file you want.

This is the link for the file:

`https://mrfstorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/mrf-even/2022-07-01_ALL-SAVERS-INSURANCE-COMPANY_Insurer_PS1-50_C2_in-network-rates.json.gz?sv=2021-04-10&st=2022-07-05T22%3A19%3A13Z&se=2022-07-09T22%3A19%3A13Z&skoid=89efab61-5daa-4cf2-aa04-ce3ba9d1d1e8&sktid=db05faca-c82a-4b9d-b9c5-0f64b6755421&skt=2022-07-05T22%3A19%3A13Z&ske=2022-07-09T22%3A19%3A13Z&sks=b&skv=2021-04-10&sr=b&sp=r&sig=NaLrw2KG239S%2BpfZibvw7%2B25AAQsf9GYZ1gFK0KRN20%3D&rscd=attachment`

To find it, you need to have the inspector open on the 'Network' tab whilst loading the page (or you can click on the file in the list when it loads the list of files on the page). When the download starts you'll see two files pop-up, one of which is the actual URL of the .gz file.

It does look the URL has a timestamp in it, so it might not work at a later time, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. However can I do this by BeautifulSoup in python ? Because I am not getting a concrete solution on how to download the file using python.

Comment: It answers your question on how to download this specific file. You simply replace the URL. If what you want is to dynamically fetch that URL, then you're asking the wrong question perhaps.